# Studio Send & Wait Widget w/ Messaging Service

Tags: twilio

I am trying to leverage the Studio Send & Wait for Reply widget with an SMS messaging service.

Outbound messages work fine.

Inbound messages are problematic.  The messaging service has been correctly configured to send inbound messages to the studio flow.  The flow looks like this:

1. Send message via Send & Wait widget
2. An active execution of the flow now exists, waiting for reply from the recipient
3. Recipient replies
4. Messaging service sends to the studio flow.  This results in a NEW execution of the flow, rather than linking it with the existing active execution.

Does anyone know how to link inbound messages from a messaging service to a running active execution of a studio flow?

Comment: I'm having this issue, too. @steven were you able to figure it out? I sent an email to Twilio support.